# How do i logout from gmail using javamail api?

Tags: gmail, jakarta-mail

I got an error like this:

> javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [ALERT] Too many
>   simultaneous connections.

I've have been told to log out the session each time. But i don't know how to do it.

Here is my code:

```
   /*...............*/
         props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
         session = Session.getInstance(props);
    try{
        store = session.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect("imap.googlemail.com", props.getProperty("userid"),
                props.getProperty("password")); // imap.mail.yahoo.com
        System.out.println("auth access success");
        f = (IMAPFolder[]) store.getDefaultFolder().list("*");
    } catch (MessagingException me) {
        System.err.print(me);
    }
  /*................*/
```

Comment: This code will work but problem is how can i log out a session???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [Folder.close(boolean)](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#close(boolean)) to release each folder and call [Store.close()](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Service.html#close()) to logout.