# ImapIdleChannelAdapter javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [ALERT] Too many simultaneous connections

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap, spring-integration

I have spring integration module in which I have configured an imap-idle-channel-adapter

```
<mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter id="fetch-email-channel-adapter" store-uri="${common.mail.imapScheme}://${common.mail.imapHost}:${common.mail.imapPort}/INBOX"
    channel="fetch-email-channel" should-delete-messages="false" should-mark-messages-as-read="true" authenticator="imapAuthenticator" auto-startup="${common.mail.autostart}"
    error-channel="errorChannel" />
```

Now when the module restarts several time I get the following error

```
    [task-scheduler-9] WARN  [ImapIdleChannelAdapter] - error occurred in idle task
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [ALERT] Too many simultaneous connections. (Failure)
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:665)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.openSession(AbstractMailReceiver.java:203)
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.openFolder(AbstractMailReceiver.java:208)
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver.waitForNewMessages(ImapMailReceiver.java:105)
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:169)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2015-06-06 00:00:00,221 [task-scheduler-9] WARN  [ImapIdleChannelAdapter] - Failed to execute IDLE task. Will attempt to resubmit in 10000 milliseconds.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure in 'idle' task. Will resubmit.
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:216)
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:169)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [ALERT] Too many simultaneous connections. (Failure)
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:665)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.openSession(AbstractMailReceiver.java:203)
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.openFolder(AbstractMailReceiver.java:208)
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver.waitForNewMessages(ImapMailReceiver.java:105)
        at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:197)
        ... 11 more
```

I have find how to close connections using [Javamail api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27702629/how-do-i-logout-from-gmail-using-javamail-api) but how to do it using imap-idle-channel-adapter

using the following spring version

> spring-integration-mail : 2.2.3.RELEASE

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you upgrade to a (much) newer version to see if it resolves the issue. There have been several bug fixes to the IMAP mail components. If you can't upgrade to the latest (4.1.5), I suggest at least 3.0.7.

Consult the [migration guides](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki) to determine any changes you might need to take account of.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do that as there are lots of other dependencies involved which makes thing quite complicated.

Comment: Well, you should at least try it; then we'll know if there's still a problem or it's fixed and, only then, someone might consider back-porting some or all of the changes to the mail module in the last 2 1/2 years since 2.2.3 was released. We're always open to considering contributions, even back-ports.

Comment: That's a quite interesting and encouraging comment. Though upgrading the version is not my sole decision to take but still I would try do it personally and see if the issue persists :)